# How to prevent Hibernate from updating column values as null in a PUT web requests?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jackson

I'm implementing CRUD operations on my spring boot application and I'm stuck on implementing the PUT http requests to update just certain values of my entity. In particular my problem is that my update method, updates all the fields in my entity regardless or not those values are `null`. I looked at countless projects on GitHub that do the same thing but I couldn't figure out what is the best solution, considering also that my Entities are of complex type as they contains relationship like @OneToMany/@OneToOne.

Here's my entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "doctor")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = Long.class)
@DynamicUpdate(value = true)
public class DoctorProfile implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(length = 10)
  private String gender;

  @NotNull
  @Column(unique = true, name = "phone_number", length = 15)
  private String phoneNumber;

  @Column(name = "specialization", length = 15)
  private String specialization;

  @Column(name = "avatar", length = 200)
  private String avatar;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "doctor_id", nullable = false)
  private Doctor doctor;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "clinic_id", nullable = false)
  @JsonBackReference
  private Clinic clinic;

//Getter-Setters omitted
}
```

Here's my Service class:

```
  public ResponseEntity<DoctorProfile> updateDoctorProfile(DoctorProfile newInfo, long id){
    
    DoctorProfile dc = doctorProfileRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(
            () -> new DoctorNotFoundException(id));

    dc.setGender(newInfo.getGender());
    dc.setPhoneNumber(newInfo.getPhoneNumber());
    dc.setSpecialization(newInfo.getSpecialization());
    dc.setClinic(newInfo.getClinic());
    dc.setAvatar(newInfo.getAvatar());

    final DoctorProfile updatedDoctor = doctorProfileRepository.save(dc);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedDoctor);
  }
```

[`@RestController` Class omitted]

As you can see I tried to use the @DynamicUpdate annotation, that is supposed to leave unchanged all the fields in the `@RequestBody` that are `null`, but that doesn't work for me.

I also though about implementing a logic that check if the fields are null or not in the @RequestBody and eventually replace them copying the values from the entity that I'm trying to update. But this solution has two problems:
•The code looks dirty;
•I can't really update values referenced by relationships like @OneToOne through `@RequestBody`,  like the Clinic or Doctor fields in my `@Entity`, since I'm not passing the entire class, but rather just the ID, and while this approach works on mysql, it doesn't on Spring JPA (and I'm still trying to figure out a solution).

I read a few answers here on stack overflow, and some suggested to create methods that update just one field at a time, since this is how the HTTP.PUT request is supposed to work. But is this really a good approach? What if I have 100,200 or even more columns? Seems impractical and repetitive to me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to have 100-200 columns? Sometimes it is acceptable to update field by field.

Also you can group information, e.g. `updatePersonalInformation` and put several fields there, or just have 1 update per entity, so DoctorProfile, Doctor, Clinic.

Also, have you considered using separate class for update, like `DoctorProfileDto` which will contain only the information you really want to update, that way, you will avoid finding yourself in a situation where you think you have some value but it is always null.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, PUT should replace a resource, so all the state that is passed should be set for it to match the intended semantics. What you want is HTTP PATCH.

If you want to use that, you will have to load the entity first, and then deserialize the JSON payload onto that entity. You can then flush that entity with dynamic update or without.

I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) which offers exactly the semantics that you are looking for.

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@UpdatableEntityView
@EntityView(DoctorProfile.class)
public interface DoctorProfileDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getGender();
    void setGender(String gender);
    String getPhoneNumber();
    void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber);
    String getSpecialization();
    void setSpecialization(String specialization);
    String getAvatar();
    void setAvatar(String avatar);
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`DoctorProfileDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, DoctorProfileDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

Here is an example of how this could look like: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence/blob/master/integration/spring-data/testsuite/webmvc/src/test/java/com/blazebit/persistence/spring/data/testsuite/webmvc/controller/DocumentController.java#L66